# Error adding playlist in discord.py music bot

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

My bot is on Heroku.For music, youtube-dl is used. When I add music, everything is fine, but when I add a playlist, an error:

ERROR: Unable to extract yt initial data; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

Tried to update didn't work.

Comment: Is it working on your local machine?

Comment: @Dominik on Heroku.

Comment: https://www.heroku.com

Comment: I am asking if the code works on your local machine, not where it is hosted. If it does not work on heroku and on your local machine, something is wrong with the code itself.

Comment: @Dominik A couple of days ago it worked, the code did not change. On the Internet, many faced this problem, for them the solution was to simply update youtube-dl, I kind of updated (but I'm not sure how to update correctly) did not help